# Best git workflow for creating multiple features on same files on a shared project?

Tags: java, git, version-control, jira

I am refactoring a 2000-line method from class A into several smaller methods in class B. As such, class A is having chunks of code replaced with single-line calls to methods defined in class B. Class B is continually being appended to since I keep writing new methods to it. My methodology thus far has been to create a new feature branch for every 3 new methods I write in class B and implement in class A. There are two workflows I am aware of:

---

**Workflow 1:**

1. i) create a ft1 branch off of dev: stage -> commit -> push -> submit pull request ->
   merge into dev.

   ii) create a ft2 branch off of dev: stage -> commit -> push -> submit pull request ->
   merge into dev.

   .

   .

   .

   n) create a ft(n) branch off of dev. . . merge into dev

---

**Workflow 2:**

2. i) create a ft1 branch off of dev: stage -> commit -> push -> submit pull request ->
   merge into dev.

   ii) create a ft2 branch off of ft1: stage -> commit -> push -> submit pull request ->
   merge into dev.

   .

   .

   .

   n) create a ft(n) branch off of ft(n - 1) . . . merge into dev

---

Keep in mind that the time between submission of a PR and merging into dev is variable and sometimes long. The issue I see with workflow 1 is that I am constantly overwriting the same area at the end of the class B file. This would result in merge conflicts that would need to manually be resolved. The issue with workflow 2 is that it does not make logical sense to branch features off of unrelated features. Sure, all the features affect the same 2 files, but they are independent apart from that. Now, correct me if I'm wrong here, but the upside to workflow2 seems to be that if I always withhold from submitting a PR for a specific feature until the feature that came directly before it is merged into dev, then there will be no merge conflicts ever with this approach. Am I correct in this assessment?

Which workflow is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow 2 dictates the order of the PRs, which could be bad if

- there are issues i.e. from code-review that you need to fix before getting it merged
- there are multiple teams working on merging the PRs, because Workflow 2 allows only one PR at a time to be submitted

I would see the disadvantage of having to resolve some conflicts as less concerning, because each onflict should be trivially solvable: "Use both textblocks, DEV before FT".